# change of fragment A in fragment B. Button from change is insaide Fragment A

Tags: android, android-fragments

The application has a single Activity(MainActiviy.java) + Fragment A, B, C, D etc ....
Sun in Activity + application in the Fragment A, want to change the Fragment B. But the shift knob is in Fragment A. So far we have always used directly in the Activity buttons and everything worked. But exchange between Fragment A and B having direct button in Fragment A, do not know how. Especially that use a bundle to send from A to B a putString.

code button Fragment A

```
{

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem

            final String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();

            final String id_stream = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_streaming)).getText().toString();

            // Starting single contact activity

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
            builder.setTitle("Select");
            // builder.setMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor ....");
            builder.setItems(new CharSequence[]
                            {getString(R.string.play_video), getString(R.string.remove_video)},
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                            // of the selected item
                            switch (which) {
                                case 0:

                                    TorrentPlayerFragmentRemote fragment6 = new TorrentPlayerFragmentRemote();


                                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                    bundle.putString("url", description);
                                    fragment6.setArguments(bundle);




                                    fragment6.onDestroyView();
                                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction6 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                    fragmentTransaction6.addToBackStack(null);
                                    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                                    fragmentTransaction6.remove(fragment6);
                                    fragmentTransaction6.replace(R.id.frame,fragment6);
                                    fragmentTransaction6.commit();

                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    // Snack Bar
                                    Snackbar bar = Snackbar.make(view, R.string.confirm_delete_playlist, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .setAction(R.string.yes, new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                                    // ---Control remote api---
                                                    new Thread() {

                                                        public void run() {

                                                            try {
                                                                HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
                                                                // note : you may also need
                                                                //HttpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)

                                                                HttpURLConnection con =  (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://dddd.ddd/remote/1.php?id="+id_stream).openConnection();
                                                                con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                                                                if(con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                                                                    //--refresh fragment
                                                                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                                                    ft.detach(playlist_torrent.this).attach(playlist_torrent.this).commit();
                                                                    //Fin refresh fragment

                                                                    // startActivity(getIntent());
                                                                    // finish();

                                             /*       final Handler handler = new Handler();
                                                    Runnable refresh = new Runnable() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void run() {
                                                            new onPreExecute().execute();
                                                            handler.postDelayed(this, 60 * 1000);
                                                        }
                                                    };
                                                    handler.postDelayed(refresh, 60 * 1000);     */
                                                                }
                                                                else{

                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                            catch (Exception e) {
                                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }.start();
                                                    // ----fin Control remote api----
                                                }
                                            });

                                    bar.show();


                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    });
            builder.create().show();

        }
    });
```

"frame" is inside Activity.

I think we should change that to receive MainActivity.java as to make the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you could pass your activity in to the constructor of your Fragment A and save it off. Then make the method on your activity to switch the fragments with something like:

```
`public void switchFragment(){
     FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
     fragmentB= (FragmentB) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentB);
     if (fragmentB == null) {
          fragmentB = FragmentB.newInstance("My Fragment B");
          fm.beginTransaction().
          replace(R.id.fragmentA, fragmentB).commit();
     }
 }`
```

Then from within FragmentA on click you can call the activity that you saved off in the constructor of FragmentA and call the switchFragment function on the activity.

Comment: I want the fragment A to press the button A and open Fragment B. Button A is inside fragment A.

Comment: Yeah so when you press button A in fragment A you can call the switch fragment method that is on the activity. You can access it because you passed the activity in to Fragment A when you created it.

Comment: public void switchFragment() Put this from Activity , in Fragment A put private Main2Activity activity; and from call this : activity.switchFragment(); ?

Comment: Yeah I believe so.